# TableSearch - Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uitableview

I study the « TableSearch » example from Apple. In this example we have a « Navigation Controller » connected to a viewController containing a « uiTableView » with cells and a « Search bar ».

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch/Listings/TableSearch_APLAppDelegate_m.html

What I try to do is do bring some amendments to the structure and try to implement the TableSearch in a "TabBar Application". So, now I have a « Tab Bar Controller » connected (for the first tab) to a "Navigation Controller » connected to the viewController containing the uiTableView with the « SearchBar.
With the help of « Exception BreakPoint » I can isolate a problem of "unrecognized selector sent to instance ». The problem seems to be in the AppDelegate, method "application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions".
Any help welcomed to understand this issue, thanks.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.window rootViewController];
APLViewController *viewController = [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
viewController.products = productArray; //————<< problem HERE
```

Comment: Are you sure that [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; is APLViewController in your case ? It looks like it's not. Please give output of that: NSLog(@"%@", [[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]class]);

Comment: 2014-03-03 16:31:29.254 TableSearch[70950:70b] UIViewController
2014-03-03 16:31:29.255 TableSearch[70950:70b] -[UIViewController setProducts:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb2f0a0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information you provided:

```
-[UIViewController setProducts:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Problem is that your main viewController is UIViewController, not APLViewController.
You need to update your code when you create TabBarController

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand your answer, but I don’t really know what to do… my storyboard and all connections seem ok. A hill behind the hill...

Comment: You have to create a custom class extending UIViewController (same as APLViewController) and make it as default UIViewController in your storyboard